# How can i get a percentage of how many users favorited a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i get a percentage of how many users favorited a post? So something like 80% of users favorite the first post. I am also using a gem called [Markable](https://github.com/chrome/markable).

In my posts controller i can favorite a post like this.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 def favorite
  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  current_user.mark_as_favorite @post
  redirect_to @post
 end
end
```

I can see all the users who have favorited a post like this

```
@post = Post.first << Test post
@post.users_have_marked_as_favorite << [user1, user2]
@post.users_have_marked_as_favorite.count << 2
```

Below are my Post and User models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
 # the markable_as :favorite is what gives me the option to favorite
 markable_as :favorite
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_marker
end
```

Comment: Can you include your `User` and `Post` models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will calculate the percentage and round it to only have 2 decimal numbers

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def favored_percentage
    (users_have_marked_as_favorite.count * 100 / User.count).round(2)
  end
end
```